# Device token is not received from iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, devicetoken

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

I successfully installed my app in iPhone, then manually turned off notifications of my app (in setting screen) and uninstalled  app from my device... Now again I installed my app in device, notification were automatically turned on but device token not received.

Comment: Did you make sure the notifications were actually turned back on in the **device** settings?

Comment: yes i am sure about this